# npm start fails after copying a project to a new directory

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

hi i move my project to a new directory and now i can't compile each time i `npm start`
I get this error : `Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/Box' in 'C:\Users\...` followed by this error
 `Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'`

I tried to rm node_modules and package-lock.json already it's not working

here is my package.json :

```js
{
  "name": "react-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@brainhubeu/react-carousel": "^2.0.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-responsive": "^8.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

thank's if you have any advice :)

Comment: component you are using @mui/material/Box, is from mui version 5, and your package.json is having v4 installed.

Comment: @Madhuri how can i made them upgrade to 5 so ?

Comment: https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/ But instead you can check your box component where it is getting called, and change it to v4 import